# Print a list in a matrix form

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, matrix

I need to print a list in matrix form. I need to remove the brackets and commas from the list. I don't know how to do that so please help me to find a solution.

This is my code:

```
import re
import itertools
import textwrap

a,b=map(int,input().split())
c=[]
pv=[]
av=[]

for i in range(a):
    row=input().split()
    c.append(row)


c=list(itertools.chain(*c))


for i in range(len(c)):
    ab=c[i]
    res="".join(a *int(b) for a, b in zip(ab[0::2],ab[1::2]))
    pv.append(res)
    
pv1=[]

for i in range(b):
    cd=pv[i::b]
    pv1.append(cd)


pv1=list(itertools.chain(*pv1))


pv2=[]

for i in range(len(pv1)):
    abd=pv1[i]
    r=textwrap.wrap(abd,3)
    pv2.append(r)



pv2=list(itertools.chain(*pv2))

pv2=[list(pv) for pv in pv2]



pavi=int(len(pv2)/b)


pv2=[pv2[i:i+pavi] for i in range(0,int(len(pv2)),pavi)]

for row in zip(*pv2):
    print(*(row))
```

**My output**:

```
2 3
a3b3c3 b1c1a7 x4y1z4
p9 a8c1 z2y2x5

['a', 'a', 'a'] ['b', 'c', 'a'] ['x', 'x', 'x']
['b', 'b', 'b'] ['a', 'a', 'a'] ['x', 'y', 'z']
['c', 'c', 'c'] ['a', 'a', 'a'] ['z', 'z', 'z']
['p', 'p', 'p'] ['a', 'a', 'a'] ['z', 'z', 'y']
['p', 'p', 'p'] ['a', 'a', 'a'] ['y', 'x', 'x']
['p', 'p', 'p'] ['a', 'a', 'c'] ['x', 'x', 'x']
```

**Expected Output:**

```
2 3
a3b3c3 b1c1a7 x4y1z4
p9 a8c1 z2y2x5

a a a b c a x x x
b b b a a a x y z
c c c a a a z z z
p p p a a a z z y
p p p a a a y x x
p p p a a c x x x
```

So this is the output I needed. I zipped the list into equal halves but I don't know how to remove the spaces and brackets. So please help me out, guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `print(*(row))` at the end, you could just do

```
print(re.sub(r"[^\w ]", "", str(row)))
```

This will remove every character that is not a word character or space.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've already imported itertools, you could use chain for printing each line:

```
for row in zip(*pv2):
    print(*itertools.chain(*row))
```

Alternatively, you could expand and break down the patterns in progressive list comprehensions:

```
width   = 3
strings = [ ['a3b3c3','b1c1a7','x4y1z4'],
            ['p9','a8c1','z2y2x5'] ]

# expand run-lengths into the repeated character sequences
strings = [ ["".join(c*int(n) for c,n in zip(*[iter(rle)]*2)) for rle in row] 
             for row in strings ] 

# break down each string based on specified wrapping width
strings = [ [ [s[i:i+width] for i in range(0,len(s),width)] for s in row]
            for row in strings ]

# combine the broken down chunks for each column
strings = [ s  for row in strings for s in map("".join,zip(*row)) ]

# print the result
for line in strings: print(*line)

a a a b c a x x x
b b b a a a x y z
c c c a a a z z z
p p p a a a z z y
p p p a a a y x x
p p p a a c x x x
```

*Note that you may need to use zip_longest for the chunk combining part if the input doesn't always produce equal size blocks of characters*